# Writing Jasmine test for Angular 2 component which uses Observables

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I am trying to test an angular 2 component that uses service calls and observable calls to get a list of data. I have imported my main app module into this spec file.

My spec file looks like this:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, fakeAsync, async } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppModule } from '../../../src/app/app.module';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { } from 'jasmine';

import { FirmService } from '../../../src/app/containers/dashboard/services/firm.service';
import { FirmListComponent } from '../../../src/app/containers/dashboard/firm-list/firm-list.component';
import { mockFirm1, mockFirm2, mockFirms } from './firm-list.mocks';
import { Firm } from '../../../src/app/containers/dashboard/models/firm.model';
import { FirmState } from '../../../src/app/containers/dashboard/services/firm.state';

describe('Firm List Component', () => {
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<FirmListComponent>;
    let component: FirmListComponent;
    let element: HTMLElement;
    let debugEl: DebugElement;
    let firmService: FirmService;
    let mockHttp;
    let stateObservable: Observable<FirmState>;
    let store: Store<FirmState>;
    let getFirmsSpy;
    let getObservableSpy;

    // utilizes zone.js in order to mkae function execute syncrhonously although it is asynchrounous
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [MaterialModule, FormsModule, AppModule],
            declarations: [FirmListComponent],
            providers: [FirmService]
        })
            .compileComponents() // compiles the directives template or any external css calls
            .then(() => {
                fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FirmListComponent); // allows us to get change detection, injector
                component = fixture.componentInstance;
                debugEl = fixture.debugElement;
                element = fixture.nativeElement;
                firmService = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(FirmService);

                getObservableSpy = spyOn(firmService, 'stateObservable')
                    .and.returnValue(new FirmState());

                getFirmsSpy = spyOn(firmService, 'getFirms')
                    .and.returnValue(Observable.of(mockFirms));
            });
    }));

    it('should be defined', () => {
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });

    describe('initial display', () => {
        it('should not show firms before OnInit', () => {
            debugEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.animate-repeat'));
            expect(debugEl).toBeNull();
            expect(getObservableSpy.calls.any()).toBe(false, 'ngOnInit not yet called');
            expect(getFirmsSpy.calls.any()).toBe(false, 'getFirms not yet called');
        });

        it('should still not show firms after component initialized', () => {
            fixture.detectChanges();
            debugEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.animate-repeat'));
            expect(debugEl).toBeNull();
            expect(getFirmsSpy.calls.any()).toBe(true, 'getFirms called');
        });

        it('should show firms after getFirms observable', async(() => {
            fixture.detectChanges();

            fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
                fixture.detectChanges();

                // **I get the correct value here, this is the table headers for the table data below that is showing 0**
                var rowHeaderLength = element.querySelectorAll('th').length;
                expect(rowHeaderLength).toBe(8);

                // **I get 0 for rowDataLength here, test fails**
                var rowDataLength = element.querySelectorAll('.animate-repeat').length;
                console.log(rowDataLength);
            });
        }));

        it('should show the input for searching', () => {
            expect(element.querySelector('input')).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
```

The first test above passes but the second one does not, I am currently getting an error that says "Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of null".

My component code looks like this:

```
 import { NgModule, Component, Input, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
 import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
 import { FlexLayoutModule } from '@angular/flex-layout';
 import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
 import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
 import { Firm } from '../models/firm.model';
 import { FirmService } from '../services/firm.service';

 @Component({
   selector: 'firm-list',
   templateUrl: './firm-list.html',
   styles: []
 })

export class FirmListComponent implements OnInit {
   public selectAll: boolean;
   public firms: Array<Firm>;
   public filteredFirms: any;
   public loading: boolean;
   public searchText: string;
   private componetDestroyed = false;

   // @Input() public search: string;

   constructor(public firmService: FirmService) { }

     public ngOnInit() {
       this.firmService.stateObservable.subscribe((state) => {
         this.firms = state.firms;
         this.filteredFirms = this.firms;
       });

      this.getFirms();
   }

    public getFirms(value?: string) {
      this.loading = true;
      this.firmService.getFirms(value).subscribe((response: any) => {
         this.loading = false;
      });
    }
}

 @NgModule({
   declarations: [FirmListComponent],
   exports: [FirmListComponent],
   providers: [FirmService],
   imports: [
       MaterialModule,
       FlexLayoutModule,
       CommonModule,
       FormsModule
     ]
 })

export class FirmListModule { }
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing some code in my spec file to account for the observable or if I'm missing something else?? Any help is appreciated.

Firm Service

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthHttp } from 'angular2-jwt';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { firmActions } from './firm.reducer';
import { FirmState } from './firm.state';

@Injectable()
export class FirmService {
   public stateObservable: Observable<FirmState>;

   constructor(private $http: AuthHttp, private store: Store<FirmState>) {
    // whatever reducer is selected from the store (in line below) is what the "this.store" refers to in our functions below.
    // it calls that specific reducer function
    // how do I define this line in my unit tests?
      this.stateObservable = this.store.select('firmReducer');
  }

public getFirms(value?: string) {
    return this.$http.get('/api/firm').map((response: Response) => {
        this.store.dispatch({
            type: firmActions.GET_FIRMS,
            payload: response.json()
        });
        return;
    });
}

public firmSelected(firms) {
    // takes in an action, all below are actions - type and payload
    // dispatches to the reducer
    this.store.dispatch({
        type: firmActions.UPDATE_FIRMS,
        payload: firms
    });
}

public firmDeleted(firms) {
    this.store.dispatch({
        type: firmActions.DELETE_FIRMS,
        payload: firms
    });
  }
}
```

My firm component html template:

```
<md-card class="padding-none margin">
  <div class="toolbar" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
    <div fxFlex class="padding-lr">
      <div *ngIf="anySelected()">
        <button color="warn" md-raised-button (click)="deleteSelected()">Delete</button>
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="!anySelected()">
        <md-input-container floatPlaceholder="never">
          <input mdInput [(ngModel)]="searchText" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" type="text" placeholder="Search" />
        </md-input-container>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="label-list" fxFlex fxLayoutAlign="end center">
      <label class="label bg-purple600"></label>
      <span>EDF Model</span>
      <label class="label bg-green600"></label>
      <span>EDF QO</span>
      <label class="label bg-pink800"></label>
      <span>LGD Model</span>
      <label class="label bg-orange300"></label>
      <span>LGD QO</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <md-card-content>
    <div class="loading-container" fxLayoutAlign="center center" *ngIf="loading">
      <md-spinner></md-spinner>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!loading">
      <table class="table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="checkbox-col">
              <md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="selectAll" (click)="selectAllChanged()" aria-label="Select All"></md-checkbox>
            </th>
            <th>
              Firm Name
            </th>
            <th>
              Country
            </th>
            <th>
              Industry
            </th>
            <th>
              EDF
            </th>
            <th>
              LGD
            </th>
            <th>
              Modified
            </th>
            <th>
              Modified By
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let firm of filteredFirms; let i = index" class="animate-repeat" [ngClass]="{'active': firm.selected}">
            <td class="checkbox-col">
              <md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="firm.selected" aria-label="firm.name" (change)="selectFirm(i)"></md-checkbox>
            </td>
            <td>{{firm.name}}</td>
            <td>{{firm.country}}</td>
            <td>{{firm.industry}}</td>
            <td>
              <span class="label bg-purple600">US 4.0</span>
              <span class="label bg-green600">US 4.0</span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <span class="label bg-pink800">US 4.0</span>
              <span class="label bg-orange300">US 4.0</span>
            </td>
            <td>{{firm.modifiedOn}}</td>
            <td>{{firm.modifiedBy}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```

Comment: Have you tried adopting the setup [shown in the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#component-with-external-template)?

Comment: I've tried moving the code back and forth between the beforeEach and the test itself but what kind of setup are you recommending there? Am I getting a null nativeElement because I'm testing the DOM before its setup and ready to be tested? Do I need to just mock the service and not add the real one in the providers?

Comment: Well, read it - they recommend *two* `beforeEach` sections, one `async` one not. It seems like in your current setup `createComponent` doesn't happen before you reach the expectation.

Comment: I'm using compileComponents.then() which the same as writing two beforeEach functions. Also, if my first test there is passing I'm thinking the template is loaded but I'm not for sure there

Answer (score 1):

Hmm I see a couple things here that could be your problem. Just to be clear, your error is coming here:

```
de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('table'));
```

You try to get the nativeElement of de, which is null. Let's assume you've troubleshot this and there's no reason for it not to exist - you could sanity check yourself and grab some other element that you "know" should exist, but I really think the issue here is trying to grab a reference to something before it exists. In this case, you detect changes AFTER trying to get a reference to a nativeElement. If your table populates the way I think it does, you need to detect changes() first, then grab a reference to what propagates up to the DOM. For sure your ngOnInit could not have occurred yet - it will not trigger when the TestBed creates the component fixture, it occurs on the first detectChanges().

Try this:

```
it('should have table headers', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('table'));
        el = de.nativeElement;        
        expect(el.textContent).toEqual('Firm Name');
    });
```

It goes further - a lot of times with tables or anything using angular's animation under the covers requires you to import either BrowserAnimationsModule or NoopAnimationsModule. Since this is a unit test, I'd just import the NoopAnimationsModule and then grab your reference and perform the test as you like.

Ok, after you pointed out the error you're getting on ngOnInit, I see what your problem is.

So this unit test isn't meant to test that service. In that vein of thought, you have a few options. Intercept the call to the service with a spy, but since it's a property, you'd have to use spyOnProperty. Or, you can just use that stub you were providing anyways. Reviewing your original post, I think that's what you're trying to do. I think this might work if you change it this way:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {
     TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [MaterialModule, FormsModule, AppModule],
        declarations: [FirmListComponent],
        providers: [{provide: FirmService, useClass: FirmStub}]
    })
        .compileComponents()
        .then(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FirmListComponent);
            component = fixture.componentInstance;
            firmStub = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(FirmService);
        });
}));
```

On that note, you will also need to provide a stateObservable property on your FirmStub, as that's being accessed in the ngOninit. You can just stub that out relatively straight forward.

```
class FirmStub {
   public stateObservable: Observable<FirmState> = new Observable<FirmState>();
   public getFirms(value?: string): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.of(mockFirms);
    }
}
```

Without the html file, I'm not sure if you actually needed that property to be populated in a certain way to test the template, but if not, that stub should work. If you do need it in a certain way, just have the FirmStub provide a more robust property.

You could also just intercept the ngOnInit all together by adding this to the test:

```
spyOn(component, 'ngOnInit');// this will basically stop anything from ngOnInit from actually running.
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yea the issue I'm having when I move the fixture.detectChanges() above the el.nativElement is that I get a "cannot read property 'subscribe' of null" which is coming from my component code inside of ngOnInit where I'm actually trying to load my firms to the page, essentially that fixture.detectChanges is calling ngOnInit which is giving me that undefined value for 'stateObservable' and then kills the tests. If I take out fixture.detectChanges() and just test if a spy has been called or any basic test it passes fine. Any idea why that 'stateObservable' in my component would me null??

Comment: I added some additional code for where I am at this point - I added a FirmStub and added an overrideComponent to try and stay out of the component but doesn't seem to work..why would it be getting undefined inside ngOnInit??

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. I'm trying to say to move your change detection up. This allows your DOM's changes to propagate and you can grab a reference to those nodes.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: Regardless of where I put fixture.detectChanges() it errors out because it calls ngOnInit which runs into this line inside my component: "this.firmService.stateObservable.subscribe". So stateObservable is undefined. Do you know, by, chance, how to mock or define the stateObservable with ngrx and redux?

Comment: My mistake. I see your point now. So this isn't meant to test that service. In that vein of thought, you can do one of two things. I will update my answer since this response format isn't friendly to illustrating it.

Comment: Thanks for the time. I was able to make some progress with the spyOn path. My main goal is to access the firm data that sits inside the <tbody> tags but that seems to be the only issue I'm still running into. When I check for the number of tr elements inside my <tbody> I am getting 0, but I get the correct number of th elements in my test.  updated my component spec code above, and I also added my component html template. Is there something I'm missing here to access the data inside the tbody element?

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that when I want to check for the correct bindings inside of my html template, I should be looking for the data in my 'mockFirms' file, not the data in my actual api call? So if the name of one of my mockFirms is "Firm 1", I should checking the component template ({{firm.name}}) toContain or toEqual "Firm 1"? Thanks again!